# get_or_create with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have a model

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

In a form I need to check if a conversation with exactly these users exists. I've tried

```
Conversation.objects.get_or_create(users=form.cleaned_data['users'])
```

but I get the error `'users' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. What can I do different to solve my problem?

Comment: In my opinion this model does not have any sense. Specific grup of users can have only one conversation? If its true you should create specyfic method for this situation in ConversationManager class.

Comment: I haven't specified all fields. A user can create a conversation with other users. I also have a Message model which has a foreign key to the conversation model

Comment: I think that you should do it like facebook did. www.facebook.com/messages/conversation-id.13123123 Looking for unique conversation based on users not by id is strange approach.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly as Facebook does. Don't you think they have a model for conversations and a model for messages? On mobile you have the option to name a conversation, so I guess it's done the same way as I'm trying

Comment: So there is no reason to use get_or_create based on users.

Comment: I would use get_or_create when creating a new message to determine if the message should be placed in an already exisiting conversation or in a new conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replace `self.cleaned_data['users']` to `form.cleaned_data['users']` where `form` is insatnce your form.